# How to make checkbox of “Ship to different address” on Woocommerce checkout page unchecked by default

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Recently I used the following to change the text of “Ship to different address” on Woocommerce checkout page

```
function shipchange( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Ship to different address?' :
           $translated_text = __( 'Other', 'woocommerce' );
           break;
    }

    return $translated_text;
}

add_filter('gettext', 'shipchange', 20, 3);
```

but I noticed that the checkbox is checked from the start. How can I have the checkbox unchecked by default?

Answer (score 20):

You can just change this in the WooCommerce shipping options.

WooCommerce–> Shipping Options–> Shipping Destination –> (select) Default to customer billing address.

"Ship to a different address" will not checked by default.

Comment: This still works in Woo 6.x

Answer (score 6):

There's a filter for this.

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', '__return_false' );`

`_return_true` makes it checked by default.

Comment: Your theme may have an interface for this.  Try adding a priority to the filter, like 99

Comment: Did you check that your theme isn't conflicting with this filter?

Comment: this is the correct answer. The "Shipping Options / Default to customer billing address." is irrelevant with the fact that the user needs to complete 2 forms